# hive-import and hive-overwrite with sqoop import all

Tags: hadoop, hiveql, sqoop

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/SomeDB --username root --hive-database test --hive-import;
```

The above command is working fine but it's duplicating the values in the destination tables. I used the below to overwrite the data.

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/SomeDB --username root --hive-import --hive-database Test --hive-overwrite
```

This replaced all the values in the table and inserted only null values. If I am removing --hive-import then also it's not working. What wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem.

sqoop import-all-tables
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/SomeDB
--username root
--hive-import
--warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse/Test
--hive-database Test
--hive-overwrite